# How to forcefully remove a record from the store, and find it again

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Whenever my backend replies with an error, I would like to:

1. Discard the record as it is in the store. I do not care what state the record is in, I just want it out of the store.
2. Request it again from the backend. The record should be in a normal state now.

Is it possible to do this? Can I do it in a `becameError`? How?

This is currently my code:

```
var entry = this.get('content');
this.transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
this.transaction.add(entry);
...
this.transaction.commit();
entry.on('becameError', this, function () { this.handleFailure(); });
```

And `handleFailure`:

```
handleFailure : function() {
    console.error('handleFailure > ');
    this.transaction.rollback();
    this.goBack();
},
```

What can I do in `handleFailure` so that the record is forgotten and requested again?
Or, as alternative, how can I clear any flag in the record so that I can continue to use it normally, without getting problems like:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `becomeDirty` on <SettingsApp.Scvoicemail:ember1027:08b8fc66-cd90-47a1-9053-4f6fefabdfe3> while in state root.error.
```

Comment: What version of Ember-Data are you using?  The transaction stuff is no longer there for ED 1.0.0-beta*

Comment: Currently still on v0.13-78-g9602df4

Comment: There are so many issues with 13, I'd jump sooner than later or you'll be fighting these issues.

Comment: Thanks. I think that won't be easy, but I'll try.

Comment: This will help a lot, https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Answer (score 0):

`record.unload()` is the way to do it, but it wasn't introduced until 1.0 beta, and it's a ton easier without the unnecessary transaction stuff.